# How to get a list of ids from all child lists

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following structure in JSON / JavaScript:

```json
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "comment",
      "answers": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "comment",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 25,
          "content": "comment"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "content": "comment",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 72,
          "content": "comment"
        },
        {
          "id": 105,
          "content": "comment"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "content": "comment",
      "answers": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get an array containing the ids of each response type comments, example

```
[25, 72, 105]
```

Can I just use `map`, `reduce` and `filter`?

What I have achieved so far was just a comment filter that has some answer:

```js
const commentsWithAnswers = comments.filter(
  (comment) => comment.answers.length !== 0
)
```

How can I extract the ids of each answer to an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an inner `.map()` and `.filter()` method. The inner `.map()` method will convert all objects in a given answer array into an array of `ids`. The `.filter()` method will ensure that we only grab the ids of objects which have the `content` of `"comment"`. The outer reduce method is used to collate all the arrays produced by the inner `.map()` method into one larger array. This is done using the spread syntax to merge the old accumulated array with the newly mapped values.

See example below:

```js
const obj = { "comments": [ { "id": 1, "content": "comment", "answers": [] }, { "id": 2, "content": "comment", "answers": [ { "id": 25, "content": "comment" } ] }, { "id": 3, "content": "comment", "answers": [ { "id": 72, "content": "comment" }, { "id": 105, "content": "comment" } ] }, { "id": 4, "content": "comment", "answers": [] } ] }

const res = obj.comments.reduce(
  (acc, {id, answers, content}) => [...acc, ...answers.filter(({content}) => content === "comment").map(({id}) => id)],
[]);

console.log(res);
```

With that being said, I prefer using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for this type of thing instead of `.reduce()`:

```js
const obj = { "comments": [ { "id": 1, "content": "comment", "answers": [] }, { "id": 2, "content": "comment", "answers": [ { "id": 25, "content": "comment" } ] }, { "id": 3, "content": "comment", "answers": [ { "id": 72, "content": "comment" }, { "id": 105, "content": "comment" } ] }, { "id": 4, "content": "comment", "answers": [] } ] }

const res = obj.comments.flatMap(({id, answers}) => answers.filter(({content}) => content === "comment").map(({id}) => id));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: how could i do if i wanted an array with ids of all comments?

Comment: what would the expected output be for that? Would it be the same?

Comment: @YungSilva I've update my answer to what I think your requirements are

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example

```js
const data = {
  comments: [
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "comment",
      answers: [],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "comment",
      answers: [
        {
          id: 25,
          content: "comment",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      content: "comment",
      answers: [
        {
          id: 72,
          content: "comment",
        },
        {
          id: 105,
          content: "comment",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      content: "comment",
      answers: [],
    },
  ],
};

const output = data.comments
  .map((entry) => entry.answers.map((item) => item.id))
  .flat();

const anotherOutput = data.comments.map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(output, anotherOutput);
```

See

- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: how could i do if i wanted an array with ids of all comments?

Comment: I updated the answer in order to get an array of comments ids